# Where are Staged files downloaded to on GCP Dataflow Workers

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am working on using GCP Dataflow Flex Templates using Java. I want to stage '/usr/local/jdk-11-latest/lib/security/cacerts' and '/usr/local/jdk-11-latest/lib/security/keystore.jks' for TLS validation. I have checked that the files are staged for the dataflow runners, but they are not downloaded to the same paths as they were used to upload. Where does GCP Dataflow put staged files it downloads from GCS?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the cloud logs of your job and search in `dataflow.googleapis.com/worker-startup` logs, you can see logging that looks like  `Downloading: gs://.../xxx.jar to /var/opt/google/tmp/download.0.219961590/file.0`.
Then when you search the `java` cmd logging, you can see all the jars are located under `/var/opt/google/dataflow/`.

Comment: Thanks I just found this out yesterday and it works! Thanks